# How to identify rarely played music files in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

Is there any way to identify the least played music files in Rhythmbox? This would be useful to do a clean up of those music files in my library that I rarely play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Rhythmbox preferences]

Rhythmbox has a play count column which can be enabled from the preferences dialog. Try Edit > Preferences and select the play count option. Then in the main Rhythmbox window click on the play count column heading to sort (or click again to reverse-sort) by play count.